# How to set custom header correctly in Node Express?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am using Node Express 4.17.

I want to use a middleware to add a custom header.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.set('My-header', 'some value');
  next();
})
```

But I can't get it in router.

It even not exists in headers.

```
app.get('/abc', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.headers['My-headers']);
  console.log(Object.keys(req.headers));
})
```

What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `res.append(name,value)` instead of `res.set(name,value)`.

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.append('My-header', 'some value');
  next();
})
```

or you can use the [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) middleware.

Let me know if this works

Answer (score 0):

imagine we have some like

```
function headers (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS,HEAD,GET,PUT,POST,PATCH");
    res.header("Accept-Language", "es, en");
    res.header(
        "Content-Security-Policy",
        "default-src 'self'; base-uri: 'self'; strict-dynamic 'self'; manifest-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'"
    );
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, Csrf-Token, Accept-Language, Content-Type, Accept, Range, X-Ahoritagram-Mime, X-Ahoritagram-Type, X-Ahoritagram-User, X-Ahoritagram-Auth, X-Ahoritagram-License, X-Ahoritagram-Size, X-Ahoritagram-Platform, X-Ahoritagram-ProductSub"
    );

    next();
}
```

later on we have some like

```
const app = express();
app.use(headers);
```

them custom headers must be before your routes